# retrieve images from one to many relation

Tags: php

I have 2 tables.
Article(idarticle int, titlea varchar(100), content text, PRIMARY KEY (idarticle))

Image(idimage int, titlei varchar(100),pic varchar(100),idarticle int,PRIMARY KEY (idimage), FOREIGN KEY (idarticle) REFERENCES Article(idarticle)).

so for each article I can get 4images. I would like to display these images according to the article selected.

```
<php>
if(isset($_GET["id"]))
{
$id = $_GET["id"];
$pdo_statement = $connect->prepare("select article.titlea, article.content,image.titlei, image.pic from article,image WHERE article.idarticle=image.idarticle AND article.idarticle=$id GROUP BY article.idarticle");
$pdo_statement->execute();
$result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
if(!empty($result)) 
{ 
foreach($result as $row) 
{
<p><?php echo $row["titlea"]; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row["titlei"]; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row["content"]; ?></p>
}
}
}
<php>
```

Any help please, how can I display the images for one aticle selected

Comment: We need more information to answer this question. What exactly is stored inside of the `pic` column of your `image` table? A URL? A local filename? A BLOB?

Comment: Inside the 'pic' column I have only the filename and the image is stored in folder upload

Comment: Be warned: that code is open for SQL injection. If you already use prepared statements, please do not include any parameters (especially those from the request) through strings!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please use `prepare()` and `execute()` properly. Prepared statements are there to prevent SQL injections, but you do not use them correctly. In your case, someone could potentially do anything they want on your database by passing a forged `id` parameter to the URL of your script...

To prevent that from happening, use

```
$pdo_statement = $connect->prepare("select article.titlea, article.content,image.titlei, image.pic from article,image WHERE article.idarticle=image.idarticle AND article.idarticle=:id GROUP BY article.idarticle");
$pdo_statement->execute([':id' => $id]);
```

#### Displaying the image

As you said, there is a filename stored inside `image.pic` that refers to a upload folder. You need to make sure that the upload folder is in the document root. If you can access images in the upload folder with the URL /upload/filename, you can simply do something like this to your foreach loop:

```
foreach($result as $row) 
{
  foreach (['titlea', 'titlei', 'content'] as $field) {
    echo "<p>{$row[$field]}</p>\n";
  }

  echo "<img src=\"/upload/{$row['pic']}\">\n";
}
```

For this to work, it requires `image.pic` to contain something like `myimage.jpg` and an image in `upload/myimage.jpg` relative to your document root.

Note that I also changed your code for displaying the title and content fields, because the code as written in your question would not work - you cannot write HTML inside of your php blocks. One thing you could do to make your code work is:

```
foreach($result as $row): ?>
  <p><?php echo $row["titlea"]; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $row["titlei"]; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $row["content"]; ?></p>
<?php
endforeach;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I need a html to display article images. How can I do that please? Inside image.pic I stored the filename and images are stored in folder 'upload'

Comment: I added an example of how you can display the image and fix the rest of your code. If a broken image is displayed in the browser, your filename or path is not correct and must be adjusted accordingly.